# Any reason why not use a "newInstance" pattern with an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

It seems like a nice way to simplify how arguments are set for fragments so I'm curious why it's not commonly depicted for creating explicit intents for starting activities?

Comment: There are developers use have `static` methods on an activity to create the `Intent` and start the activity. I'm not aware of any Google samples that do it. It's a fairly nice practice, particularly with the support annotations to help provide compile-time sanity checks for the values to go into extras. So, I'd describe it more as "not commonly depicted" more so than "isn't recommended".

Comment: Good points on the "not commonly depicted" - that's more in line what what I wanted ask.  I was thinking the same things about the benefits with regard to compile-time sanity checks for the values loaded into extras.  I just couldn't think of downsides.  Maybe there aren't any downsides?

Comment: One quasi-downside is that there's no enforcement mechanism, short of code reviews and electro-shock therapy. You can create the convenience method to start the activity, but somebody could bypass that and start the activity themselves directly. So, you still need all your defensive programming bits.

Comment: I think your comments are the best answer so far so if you combine them into an answer I'll go ahead and check this as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* with creating a `static` method to build the `Intent` to start an activity, or even having a `static` method that starts the activity. You can also go with an `IntentBuilder` pattern, where you expose a builder-style API that generates the `Intent`, for scenarios where a simple method would be unworkable. I take that approach in [my CWAC-Cam2 library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2), for example.

Google hasn't been promoting the pattern, though you will see this sort of code if you generate a service from the Android Studio wizard, IIRC. However, Google isn't really in the business of trying to show every possible programming pattern.

The biggest limitation that I know of is that there is no enforcement mechanism. While you can *offer* these sorts of facilities, there is nothing stopping developers from bypassing or ignoring them. IOW, the classic create-an-`Intent`-and-go API is "public", and you cannot somehow make it private. So, your activity needs to assume the worst, and have whatever defensive programming you feel is appropriate.

Comment: I suppose if someone creates the Intent manually but with all the required stuff in the Bundle that's probably fine. What's the standard practice if someone creates the Activity without all the requirements in the Bundle? Throw and IllegalStateException or something like that?

Comment: @TylerJames: Ideally, you gracefully degrade as best you can, particularly in cases where the consuming code is some other app (e.g., your activity/fragment is in a library). So, for example, use default values where possible, rather than crashing hard. If you run into a situation where you legitimately cannot proceed, show some "I kinna do it, cap'n!" UI (in case this winds up happening in production) and yell at the developer via LogCat. If you want, see if you're in a debuggable app, and if so, *then* throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think its just because you can have many fragments, but you probably only have a handful of activities.

Also, you are more likely to pass args to a fragment, less so with an activity.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can create fragments using `new` operator inside `newinstance` while that is not the case with activities, activities can only be `started` using​ intents in code. While the creation is handled by OS​. You never call `new` to create a new activity unlike fragments.